# NativeScript can only run in Xcode version 6.0 or greater

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript

I have created new project based on this docs: https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/getting-started/quick-start/

When I ran `tns run ios --bundle` 
I got this error:
**NativeScript can only run in Xcode version 6.0 or greater**

But I have much higher version:
**Xcode: 10.1** on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6

When I ran `tns doctor` I get: **No issues were detected.**

Where could be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried xcode-select --print-path to make sure you're pointing at the correct IDE version?

Comment: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer seems correct. I have only 1 installed.

Comment: Try one of the solutions posted here https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3189#issuecomment-344507032

Comment: Thx. But I saw this link, and I have tried it before and also now. But unsuccessful. And if you see xcode-select --print-path from prev comment, references to same directory.

Comment: sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer this didn't help

Comment: Open your Xcode>Prefrences>Location and see if the Command Line Tools is showing the latest build.

Comment: Yes, Xcode 10.1 (10B61) - /Applications/Xcode.app

Comment: Can you please post the output of the following commands:
1. `xcodebuild -version`
2. `xcodebuild -version | head -n 1`
3. `xcodebuild -version | head -n 1 | sed -e 's/Xcode //'` ?

I assume there's some problem with the way NativeScript CLI tries to determine your Xcode version (it is using the third command)`. The output will help us to determine what is the problem.

Comment: 1) Xcode 10.1
Build version 10B61 2) Unknown option: n 3) Unknown option: n

Comment: So the problem is that your `head` command is overwritten by something and it is not the default `head` that usually works on macOS. Can you please ensure your `head` command is working properly? You can try to find the `head` executable with `which head` command.

Comment: yes, seems it is overwritten by xampp, because which head gives: /Applications/XAMPP/bin/head.. I will try to figure out, how can i revert changes. But this commands just fetch something from result. If you want to know version of xcodebuild then 10.1 is the version

Comment: oh, now I understood, this `head` command is used by NativeScript, thats why its not working correctl